# Powershell's -split behaves differently depending on method parameters

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

If you split a `string`, you get a `string[]`.

```
$foo = "apple,banana,coconut"
Write-Output $foo.GetType()

$foo = $foo -split ","
Write-Output $foo.GetType()
```

If you split a paramaterized `string`, you get a `string`.

```
Function Get-Foo() {
    param ( 
      [string] $foo
    )

    Write-Output $foo.GetType()

    $foo = $foo -split ","
    Write-Output $foo.GetType()
}
```

Why?

I researched this and didn't turn anything up; Powershell's documentation [on split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_split?view=powershell-6) was largely unhelpful.

Comment: No, you don't get a `string`. You get a `string[]` that is then forcibly converted to a `string` because you gave `$foo` an explicit type. Try `$bar = $foo -split ","`. (To replicate this in your first example, try `[string] $foo = "apple, banana, coconut"`.)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand - I want the parameter to be string.  Later on, I want it to be an iterable string array. Are you saying that `[string] $foo` will ensure that `$foo` remains a `string`, even when I try to make it a `string[]`?

Comment: That is indeed precisely what I'm saying. PowerShell is loosely typed, but if you override this by explicitly typing your variables, it stops being loosely typed. `$a = 5; $a = "banana"` is fine; `[int] $a = 5; $a = "banana"` is a conversion error. Remove `[string]` from your parameter declaration and your code will work as-is (but then you lose some clarity and reliability).

Comment: Thanks Jeroen - this was the issue.

Comment: Note that while you cannot change the type by reassigning a value, you can override it explicitly by re-specifying a type: `[string[]] $foo = $foo -split ","` will also work. I don't recommend this over either declaring a new variable (why throw away the original parameter?), or loosening the original type, but the option is there.

Comment: Yeah, that conceptually makes sense.  I ended up opting to get rid of `[string]` altogether to prevent this weird implicit-type-conversion-enforcement behavior.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference is that in your first example, you never declared the variable, so you can assign it values of any type and it will accept them without coercion, altering its type to match:

```
PS > $foo = "apple,banana,coconut"
PS > Write-Output $foo.GetType().Name
String
PS > $foo = $foo -split ","
PS > Write-Output $foo.GetType().Name
String[]
PS > $foo = 1
PS > Write-Output $foo.GetType().Name
Int32
```

But once you've explicitly declared `$foo`'s type with `[string]`, `$foo.GetType()` will continue to report `string`, and anything you assign to it will be coerced to `string`. You can't change the type of a declared variable just by assigning it a new value:

```
PS > [string] $foo = "apple,banana,coconut"
PS > Write-Output $foo.GetType().Name
String
PS > $foo = $foo -split ","
PS > Write-Output $foo.GetType().Name
String
PS > $foo = 1
PS > Write-Output $foo.GetType().Name
String
```

You can change the type by re-declaring it, though. Even within a function:

```
PS > [Int32] $foo = $foo
PS > Write-Output $foo.GetType().Name
Int32
```

Note that such a redeclaration assignment will fail if the value is not interpretable as the new type:

```
PS > [string] $foo = "apple,banana,coconut"
PS > [Int32] $foo = $foo
Cannot convert value "apple,banana,coconut" to type "System.Int32". Error: "Input string was not in a correct format."
```

As far as I know, there's no way to "un-declare" a variable's type so it goes back to accepting any type of value, short of removing the variable entirely with [`Remove-Variable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/remove-variable?view=powershell-6).

Comment: Thanks Mark - is it `$foo.GetType()` causing this enforcement, or the strongly-typed function parameter `[string] $foo` (as Jeroen mentioned)?

Comment: It's the declaration - whether as a function parameter or not. I added examples.

Comment: Yyyyyyyyyep. I wouldn't have expected PowerShell to allow for mixed strong/loose typing conventions (at least not in this way).  Thanks Mark.